# Can you obtain private key d and compute plaintext from El-Gamal?

Tags: encryption, rsa, diffie-hellman, elgamal-encryption, decryption

Given an Elgamal encryption scheme with public parameters  $k_{pub}=(p,\alpha,\beta)$ and an unknown private key $k_{pr}=d$.

Due to an erroneous implementation of the random number generator of the encrypting party, the following relation holds for two temporary keys:

$k_{M,\,j+1}= k^{2}_{M,\,j}$   mod p

Given $n$ consecutive ciphertexts
($k_{E_1},y_1)$,($k_{E_2},y_2), \ldots,(k_{E_n},y_n)$

to the plaintexts ${x_1},{x_2}, \ldots,{x_n}$.

Furthermore, **the first plaintext $x_1$ is known** (e.g., header information).

With this, I concluded that:

I believe it is possible to compute the private key $d$ from the given information. To do this, we can solve for private key $x$ in $\beta = \alpha^x \bmod p$.

But as my understanding of the topic is naïve, I may not have come to the right conclusions.

Comment: @kelalaka Thanks, I hope the current edits make it easier to read now.

Comment: Isn't the encryption $y_i = x_i \beta^{k_{M,i}}$?

Comment: @kelalaka yes it is, and so, we would solve for $^{k_M,_i}$ to find ${x_i}$

Comment: Then, to solve the next, you need to use the square relation. Show that $\beta^{k_M,_{i+1}} = (\beta^{k_M,_i})^2$. Note that you have very bad notation $k_i$ was enough.

Comment: Is $k_{M,j}$ temporary public key or private key of the encrypting party

Comment: And if it could be done, wouldn't I myself be able to calculate anyone private key ? Because, the encrypting party can control the temporary private or public key, however she wants.